# Get content from remote html page

Tags: php, curl

I'm looking for a way to get specific content from a remote web page

The content I want to get are inside javascript variables, this kind :

var Example1 = 0;
var Example2 = 14;

The name of the variable remain the same and the content is only numbers

Thank you

Comment: I'm at this point : $url = "Myurl";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl)

$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML( $output);

Comment: Then I don't know how to identify and get the content of the variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find scripts in html source by DomDocument and  then variable  declaration by regex

```
$DOM = new DomDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML( $output);

$res = [];
$scripts = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('script');
$lnt = $scripts->length;
for($i=0; $i < $lnt; $i++) {
    preg_match_all('/var\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*;/', $DOM->saveHtml($scripts->item($i)), $m);
    $res = array_merge($res, array_combine($m[1], $m[2]));
}
print_r($res);
```

[demo](https://eval.in/583242)

Comment: Thanks a lot it works !

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!